String manipulation using readlines and organizing results based off next line
I have a long text file with a lot of very similar lines. A few of them are incorrect and need to be adjusted.
An example of such lines are:
> set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET description "Contact: Engineering
> Permit test sharepoint server web access"
> set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANE T4-SPTST-TO-WEB
> set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANE T4-SPTST-TO-WEB 
> lots of stuff to add her
> a few lines here.
> set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET pre-rulebase security rules

The goal is to ensure that every line starts with set.. and if it doesn't, that means it belongs to the most recent line's set line.
I've started with reading all of the lines in and then trying to look ahead to see if "set" doesn't exist. I'm getting mixed results:
skip_line = False
c = 0

with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
lines = f.readlines()



for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    if skip_line:
        if i+c < len(lines):
            i+=c
    set_line = lines[i].rstrip()
    skip_line - False
    for j in range(i+1, len(lines)):
        while not lines[j].startswith("set"):
            set_line = set_line + lines[j].rstrip()
            c+=1
            j+=1
            skip_line = True
    print(set_line)

this should be the reult:
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET  description "Contact: EngineeringPermit test sharepoint server web access"
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET4-SPTST-TO-WEB group-tag MigratedFromT4
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANE T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip anylots of stuff to add herea few lines here.
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET pre-rulebase security rules T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip any

but I'm getting a lot of mixed results. Some are correct, and sometimes it just repeats.
How best to parse this and clean it up. EVERY line should start with "Set"... anything else should be brought back to the most recent "Set" line.
I feel I'm getting closer but I keep getting into infinite loops and repeated lines. It's just a logic problem and my Python is rusty to say the least.
Thoughts?

The easiest way to do it is by using Ruby's slice_before to cut up the list into chunks that you want, then joining each chunk together. Unfortunately, Python doesn't have it.
So we'll just have to write it.
def slice_before(iterable, predicate):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        prev_item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    
    group = [prev_item]

    for item in iterator:
        if predicate(item):
            yield group
            group = []
        group.append(item)
    
    if group:
        yield group

With that, the problem is trivial:
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

fixed_lines = [
    ' '.join(part.strip() for part in chunk)
    for chunk in slice_before(lines, lambda line: line.startswith('set '))
]

for line in fixed_lines:
    print(line)
# => set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET  description "Contact: Engineering  Permit test sharepoint server web access
#    set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET4-SPTST-TO-WEB group-tag MigratedFromT4
#    set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANE T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip any  lots of stuff to add here  a few lines here.
#    set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET pre-rulebase security rules T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip any

EDIT: If you take a look at the structure of slice_before, it is equivalent to the code by Tim Roberts, just abstracted (so it can be applied to any similar problem). Effectively, the two answers are the same.

This works so far. The actual file is 150,000 lines long so we'll see how it handles that. There are a lot of new items in this code for me to learn and I appreciate that!

If the file is too large to process in-memory, you can skip f.readlines(), and just use the iterable f (which yields individual lines) instead of the lines list. slice_before just wants an iterable with lines, doesn't really matter if it gets a list or a file-like object.

You're making this harder than it needs to be.  Just use an "accumulator", and print it when the line is complete.
data = """\
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET  description "Contact: Engineering
Permit test sharepoint server web access
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET4-SPTST-TO-WEB group-tag MigratedFromT4
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANE T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip any
lots of stuff to add here
a few lines here.
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET pre-rulebase security rules T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip any"""


gather = ''
for line in data.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('set'):
        if gather:
            print(gather)
        gather = line
    else:
        gather += ' '+line
if gather:
    print(gather)


Assuming that first line always starts with set  you can write something like:
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

c = lines[0].rstrip()
for l in lines[1:]:
    l = l.rstrip()
    if not l.startswith('set '):
        c += l
    else:
        print(c)
        c = l
print(c)

UPD: Added the print to correctly deal with the last line.

This seems close, on first inspection is leaves out the last line. I did learn something on this one for sure.

@Nathan Thank you. I've edited it to correctly deal with last line.

You can split the content of the file into records by '\nset ', and for each record, split the lines and rejoin them with an empty string, and finally join the records back into a string with '\nset ':
# data = f.read() in your actual code
data = """\
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET  description "Contact: Engineering
Permit test sharepoint server web access"
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET4-SPTST-TO-WEB group-tag MigratedFromT4
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANE T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip any
lots of stuff to add here
a few lines here.
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET pre-rulebase security rules T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip any"""

print('\nset '.join(''.join(record.splitlines()) for record in data.split('\nset ')))

This outputs:
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET  description "Contact: EngineeringPermit test sharepoint server web access"
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET4-SPTST-TO-WEB group-tag MigratedFromT4
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANE T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip anylots of stuff to add herea few lines here.
set device-group PA7050-T4-EXTRANET pre-rulebase security rules T4-SPTST-TO-WEB source-hip any

Demo here
